# How to filter user by spring security role in domain

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

Is that possible? If not then how do i filter in my gsp a specific role for this code?

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: tableInstance, field: 'user', 'error')} ">
<label for="user">
    <g:message code="table.user.label" default="User" />        
</label>
<g:select id="user" name="user.id" from="${rms.User.list()}" optionKey="id" value="${tableInstance?.user?.id}" class="many-to-one" noSelection="['null': '']"/>
```

The snippet above is for the basic create and edit functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sec:access` tag, provided by spring-security plugin.

```
<sec:access expression="hasRole('ROLE')">
      <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: tableInstance, field: 'user', 'error')} ">
       <label for="user">
          <g:message code="table.user.label" default="User" />        
       </label>
       <g:select id="user" name="user.id" from="${rms.User.list()}" optionKey="id" value="${tableInstance?.user?.id}" class="many-to-one" noSelection="['null': '']"/>
</sec:access>
```

or you can use `sec:ifAnyGranted` tag

```
<sec:ifAnyGranted roles="ROLE1, ROLE2, ...">
    ....
</sec:ifAnyGranted>
```

**EDIT**

```
def users = UserRole.findAllByRole(Role.get('ROLE'))*.user.unique()
```

Comment: those tags only render the the code snippet if it's true. what if i only want retrieve users with a ROLE_sampleROLE from the user.list()?

Comment: This is my code `def users = SecUserSecRole.findAllBySecRole(SecRole.get('Server'))*.secUser.unique()`. hmm for some reason it gives me an error `Provided id of the wrong type for class rms.SecRole. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String`. im using the default autogenerated methods for spring security plugin.

Comment: use Role.findAllByAuthority('ROLE')

Comment: oh this works tnx. btw can you find by two roles? and still assign them to `def users`? like if you can role 1 or role 2